# How to Freeze Gridview Header having dynamic Columns?

Tags: css, asp.net, .net, gridview

Aspx Page: Below is my Gridview, Column name as generated dynamically

```
<div id="header" style="height: 200px;overflow:scroll ">
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" >
 <HeaderStyle CssClass="fixedHeader" />
 </asp:GridView>
 </div>
```

Css Class To Freeze Header :

```
    .fixedHeader
    {
        background-color:Gray;
        position: relative;
        cursor: default;            
        top: expression(document.getElementById("header").scrollTop-2); 
        z-index: 10;

    }
```

I did all by javascript,jquery still not working(source example : asspsnippet,codeproject, etc etc) nothing works. Kindly help me Thanks

Answer (score 0):

SOLUTION 1:

1. Set the GridView to have thead as header and tbody as body. In RowDataBound set the GridView.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
2. Use the idea from here: http://css-tricks.com/snippets/jquery/persistant-headers-on-tables/
3. Modify a little bit the code to wait for loading images and then modify the width of the th elements:

   window.onload = function () {
       $("table.tableWithFloatingHeader").each(function () {
            $(this).wrap("");

   ```
       $("tr:first", this).before($("tr:first", this).clone());
       clonedHeaderRow = $("tr:first", this);
       clonedHeaderRow.addClass("tableFloatingHeader");
       clonedHeaderRow.css("position", "absolute");
       clonedHeaderRow.css("top", "0px");
       clonedHeaderRow.css("left", "0px");
       clonedHeaderRow.css("visibility", "hidden");

       var row_ths = $("tr:nth-child(2)", this).children("th");
       var crow_ths = $("tr:nth-child(1)", this).children("th"); ;

       for (var i = 0; i < row_ths.size(); ++i) {
           crow_ths.eq(i).width(row_ths.eq(i).width() + 2);
       }
   });
   ```

This works on IE8, FF and Chorme.

SOLUTION 2:

> For this feature we have use Jquery and a bit of Javascript too.This
>   will make Gridview Data scrollable while the header has been freezed
>   on top.This Will help us while looking at large amount of data, and
>   want to know that which column relate to which heading.

**[SOURCE](http://hightechnology.in/scrollable-gridview-data-with-fixed-header-using-jquery/)**

Answer (score 0):

Complete answer based on Solution 1 (Works Great, Looks Great).

Add this to your aspx.

```
 <style>
    .floatingHeader {
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      visibility: hidden;
      background-color:antiquewhite;
       z-index: 1000;
    }
    </style>

<script>

function UpdateTableHeaders() {
    $(".persist-area").each(function () {

        var el             = $(this),
            offset         = el.offset(),
            scrollTop      = $(window).scrollTop(),
            floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader", this)

        if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + el.height())) {
            floatingHeader.css({
                "visibility": "visible"
            });
        } else {
            floatingHeader.css({
                "visibility": "hidden"
            });
        };
    });
}

    // DOM Ready
    $(function() {

        $(window)
         .scroll(UpdateTableHeaders)
         .trigger("scroll");

    });
    window.onload = function () {
        $("table.tableWithFloatingHeader").each(function () {
            $(this).wrap("<div class='divTableWithFloatingHeader' style='position:relative'></div>");

            $("tr:first", this).before($("tr:first", this).clone());
            clonedHeaderRow = $("tr:first", this);
            clonedHeaderRow.addClass("floatingHeader");


            var row_ths = $("tr:nth-child(2)", this).children("th");
            var crow_ths = $("tr:nth-child(1)", this).children("th"); ;

            for (var i = 0; i < row_ths.size(); ++i) {
                crow_ths.eq(i).width(row_ths.eq(i).width() );
            }
        });
    }
    window.onresize = function () {
        $("table.tableWithFloatingHeader").each(function () {

            clonedHeaderRow = $("tr:first", this);

            var row_ths = $("tr:nth-child(2)", this).children("th");
            var crow_ths = $("tr:nth-child(1)", this).children("th");;

            for (var i = 0; i < row_ths.size() ; ++i) {
                crow_ths.eq(i).width(row_ths.eq(i).width());
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

Now on your table add the following two classes persist-area tableWithFloatingHeader with HeaderStyle Class of presist-header

```
 <asp:GridView EnableViewState="false"  ID="grid_Results" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Class="persist-area tableWithFloatingHeader">
```

It will work.

If you want to also change the color of the header you need to do the following two steps.

add    right after the

and in the code behind aspx.vb add to the databound event of the grid

```
   Protected Sub grid_Results_DataBound(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles grid_Results.DataBound
        If grid_Results.HeaderRow IsNot Nothing Then
            grid_Results.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader
        End If
    End Sub
```